# debug assertion failed _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) C++&Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to learn C++. I get this "Debug Assertion Failed" error when running my code.I don't know where I'm wrong and how to solve this problem. I have debugged this program, but it didn't have any errors until the program ended.

```
int main()
{
    Mat image;
    Mat output;
    Mat gray_prev;
    Mat gray;

    string imageName, outputName, rectName;
    cout << "please input the name of file:";
    getline(cin, imageName);
    cout << "please input the name of output:";
    getline(cin, outputName);
    cout << "please input the name of rectfile:";
    getline(cin, rectName);

    image = imread(imageName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    output = imread(outputName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(!image.empty() && !output.empty())
    {
        cvtColor(image, gray_prev, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvtColor(output, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }

    Rect rect1;
    Rect rect2;
    char cstring1[1000];
    char cstring2[1000];
    int x, y, w, h;

    fstream f;
    f.open(rectName, fstream::in);
    f.getline(cstring1, sizeof(cstring1));
    sscanf(cstring1, "%i,%i,%i,%i", &x, &y, &w, &h);
    rect1 = Rect(x, y, w, h);
    f.getline(cstring2, sizeof(cstring2));
    sscanf(cstring2, "%i,%i,%i,%i", &x, &y, &w, &h);
    rect2 = Rect(x, y, w, h);

    vector<vector<Point2f>> points1(2); //存储前后两帧特征点
    vector<vector<Point2f>> points2(2);
    vector<uchar> status;
    vector<float> err;

    //points[0].resize(rect1.width*rect1.height);
    //points[1].resize(rect2.width*rect2.height - rect1.width*rect1.height);
    for(int j=rect2.y; j<(rect2.y+rect2.height); j++){
        for(int i=rect2.x; i<(rect2.x+rect2.width); i++){   
            if( i>=rect1.x && i<=(rect1.x+rect1.width)
                && j>=rect1.y && j<=(rect1.y+rect1.height))
            {
                points1[0].push_back(Point2f(i, j));
            }
            else
            {
                points2[0].push_back(Point2f(i, j));
            }
        }
    }



    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
        gray_prev,
        gray,
        points1[0], 
        points1[1],
        status,
        err);

    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
        gray_prev, 
        gray,
        points2[0],
        points2[1],
        status,
        err);

    for(int i=0; i<points1[1].size(); i++)
    {
        circle(output, points1[1][i], 1, Scalar::all(0), (-1));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<points2[1].size(); i++)
    {
        circle(output, points2[1][i], 1, Scalar(255,0,0), (-1));
    }

    imshow("optimalflow", output);
    waitKey(0);

    f.close();

}
```

The picture is the problem I have encountered. Please help me.

Comment: *I have debugged this program, but it didn't have any errors until the program ended.* -- That is because the heap corruption detection isn't done until the program exits.  Remove the last two calls to `calc...` and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, then it is one of those two calls causing the issue.

Comment: Wrong libraries! Check that you're not using OpenCV debug libs in release, or viceversa. Be sure that OpenCV libs are compiled with the same compiler of your project, with the same architecture (eg x86 vs x64)